# Java verbose:gc How to read the output?

Tags: java, performance, verbosegc

I have a Java application which has some performance issues and someone recommend me to run it in verbose:gc mode.
This has been done, but I don't know how to interpret the logging.
Is it possible to explain me what it all means or to advise me as what I can do to increase performance?

Output log can be found on : http://pastebin.com/uDNPEGcd

Thanks in advance,
Kind regards,
Maarten

Comment: That link is no longer valid. (which is a reason why we should not use links in questions and answers anyway if we don't specify the content...). If you still have it, put the log in the question directly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`verbose:gc` prints right after each gc collection and prints details about each generation memory details. Here is blog on how to read [verbose gc](http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.com/2011/10/verbosegc-output-tutorial-java-7.html)

If you are trying to look for memory leak, verbose:gc may not be enough. Use some visualization tools like `jhat` (or) `visualvm` etc.,

```
 4416K->512K(4928K), 0.0081170 secs

Before GC used memory is 4416K
After GC used memory is 512K
Total allocated memory is 4928K
```