# Apache HttpClient - Out Of Memory Issue

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a processor that reads messages from Apache Kafka and sends the data to a REST Endpoint.

The server only has 4 cores and 4 GB ram, out of which a max of 2GB is allocated to the java process

Messages are produced and consumed at the rate of 4k/second.

After running couple of minutes, the program goes out of memory.

- What is the best way to call http rest end-points asynchronously and not wait for response
- How to manage the httpClient connection? I was under the impression that I need to start the client an never close it so I can reuse the connection
- Do you see any issues with the below code

public class SomeProcesor implements BProcessor {

```
private ThreadPoolExecutor exec = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
private CompletionService<Boolean> pool = new ExecutorCompletionService<Boolean>(exec);
CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = null ; 

@Override
public void begin() {
    httpclient = HttpAsyncClients.createDefault();
    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectionRequestTimeout(5000).setConnectTimeout(5000).setSocketTimeout(5000).build();
    HttpAsyncClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();
    // Start the client
    httpclient.start();

}

@Override
public void process(MessageAndMetadata<?, ?> mMData, List<Map> events) {

    List<Map<String, Object>> listMap = new ArrayList<>();  

    // loop and extract the data from events into the above List
    //..
    //..

    // submit to seperate thread to post to HTTP
    pool.submit(new HttpThread(listMap);
}

private class HttpThread implements Callable<Boolean> {
    List<Map<String, Object>> listMap = null;
    public HttpThread(List<Map<String, Object>> listMap) {
        this.listMap = listMap;
    }
    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        return postToHttp(listMap);
    }
}

private Boolean postToHttp(List<Map<String, Object>> listMap) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    for (Map<String, Object> map : listMap) {

        try {
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("https://myserver:8080/services/collector");
            postRequest.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/json");
            postRequest.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
            postRequest.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONNECTION, "keep-alive");

            StringEntity input = new StringEntity(methodToConvertMapToJSON(map));
            input.setContentType("application/json");
            postRequest.setEntity(input);

            httpclient.execute(postRequest, null);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: I would suggest enabling [`verbose:gc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889831/java-verbosegc-how-to-read-the-output) (and perhaps profiling) to determine *why* you're exhausting memory. I might also move the `HttpClient` to an [Object Pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern).

Comment: The processor class is instantiated only once, that is why I was initiating the httpClient object inside the begin. Why do we need to move it to Object Pool?

Comment: And you only have **one** processor? For 4,000 messages per second?

Comment: Ah..good point. I have a facility to increase the number of instances of the consumers. So that is why you want the single HttpClient in a Pool?

Comment: Do I ever need to close the connection? And for pooling are you talking about something like - https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html - section 2.3.3?

Answer (score 3):

need consume the http response or release connection, otherwise the connection will consume resources.
change

```
httpclient.execute(postRequest, null);
```

to

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(postRequest, null).get();
if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
// do something
}
// release the connection, better add to a finally clause
postRequest.releaseConnection();
```

Comment: you mean releaseConnection() even before the response is obtained? Does it not abort the original request itself?

Comment: if I am waiting for the response, how is it considered asynchronous?

Comment: The execute methods doesn't return HttpResponse!

Comment: using .get() to get the HttpResponse