# Java class instances are not destroyed

Tags: java, android, callback, garbage-collection

I am building an android app that fetches data from a hardcoded url.

Because the fetching can take a while, I first wrote an interface to support callbacks

```
public interface MyCallBack {
   void data_received(String data);
}
```

The in the main activity, I implemented `MyCallBack`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implments MyCallBack {

  @Override
  public void data_received(String data) {
    Log.d("got data", data);
    // do something useful with data...
  }

  public void btn_getData_clicked(View view) {
       // a button is clicked, and fetching is started:
       BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker(this);
       bw.execute("https://randomuser.me/api/");

      // after this point, bw does not leave the heap, 
     //  because BackgroundWorker keeps a reference to (this)
  }
}
```

I want my code to make a separate fetch whenever the button is pressed.
But I also want the consumed/done/already called back instances to go away, and leave the heap since there is no point in them staying.

So, in BackgroundWorker class, I set the caller to null right after calling the interface method:

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    MyCallBack caller;   // object to be called back when data arrives

    private static int instances_counter = 0;   // counts bw instances

    BackgroundWorker(MyCallBack cb) {
      caller = cb;
      instances_counter ++;
      Log.d("new bw object created", "current count: " + instances_counter );
    }

   @Override protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
      instances_counter --;
      Log.d("bw object destroyed","remaining count: " + instances_counter );
   }
    
   @Override String doInBackground(...) {...} // satisfy AsynTask 
   // and do the actual URL post/get stuff then forward the output
    // to onPostExecute() method

   
   @Override void onPostExecute(String s) {
      // I can check if caller is null first, but you get the idea.
      caller.data_received(s);

      caller = null;   // just so that this instance has no pointer to activity
   }
}
```

Now when I click the button multiple times, I can see the objects getting created, one by one. and I get the data each time inside my activity.

> D/new bw object created: current count: 1
>
> D/got data: {"results":[{"gender":"female" ...

---

> D/new bw object created: current count: 2
>
> D/got data: {"results":[{"gender":"male" ...

---

> D/new bw object created: current count: 3
>
> D/got data: {"results":[{"gender":"female" ...

---

> D/new bw object created: current count: 4
>
> D/got data: {"results":[{"gender":"female" ...

---

> D/new bw object created: current count: 5
>
> D/got data: {"results":[{"gender":"male" ...

But they are never destroyed. I am afraid that I am making a memory leak somewhere and that my app will at one point crash due to poor memory management on my part.

Why these instances are not being destroyed?

Comment: @ScaryWombat `static` is correct here. He wants to have a global variable counting the instances.

Comment: OP *instances are not being destroyed* - how do you know ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat because the `Log.d` in `finalize()` is never getting called

Comment: Are you sure that `gc` is happening?

Comment: @ScaryWombat How can I tell if it does?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889831/java-verbosegc-how-to-read-the-output

Comment: it's written nowhere that finalize should be called anytime soon. Have you profiled your application with proper tools? I have tested a code similar to yours and instances are collected after reaching a count of 300 (pc, not mobile, but still...). You shouldn't be making any assumption basing on a output log...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A log output in the `finalize` method is not a proper way to determine if an object causes memory leaks or not.

The only part that might trigger doubts is the fact the your `AsyncTask` instances hold a strong reference not just to any callback but to your entire `Activity`.

Still, the `Garbage Collector` is **well trained** to handle circular references anyway, but I admit I don't know whether it will wait until the `Activity` is gc'ed to collect the `AsyncTask`'s as well or it will do it as soon as it can.

In any case, you can wrap your `Callback` references inside a `WeakReference<T>`

```
private WeakReference<MyCallBack> caller;   // object to be called back when data arrives
// ...
caller = new WeakReference<>(cb);
// ...
if (caller.get() != null)
     // call callback
```

and it should give you a major sense of security that the tasks will be collected as soon as memory is needed.

> But I also want the consumed/done/already called back instances to go away, and leave the heap since there is no point in them staying.

This is honestly not up to you to decide.